# Nested LinearLayout in FrameLayout does not match parent

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have the following layout, inflated in a FrameLayout class :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The nested LinearLayout does not match parent as specified but wrap it's content to the size of the button, I have also tried to set match parent to the height of the FrameLayout,

What could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

use match_parent for FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have already tried, in the layout editor it seem to work, but when I inflate the layout in a class which extends FrameLayout, it's stay as it was(not matching the parent), in the FrameLayout class, there is nothing actually, just inflating the layout

Comment: your class must implement Fragment and not FrameLayout ?

Comment: No, i subclass FrameLayout and want to inflate this xml(I'll then replace the xml tag by a merge)